# How do I compare my arguments passed to the method in my spy

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I am very new to Jasmine, and I am trying to compare an argument passed to my spy.  I am trying to use the method, I did a lot of research and I found I can use the toHaveBeenCalledWith as follows:

jasmine.toHaveBeenCalledWith(request.searchResult).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...).

Unfortunately, my object is quite complex, and I want to compare all the return values in my object.   Here is the structure of my object:

```
   {
     "Result":{
       "productInformation":{
         "inStock":"true",
         "inventoryCode":"PRDCT-QQ011",
        
      "OrderType":[
         "MERCH-DDD",
         "APPAREL"
      ],
       "productAttributes":[
          {
           "key":"product",
           "value":"Polo Shirt"
          },
         {
           "key":"ColorCode",
           "value":"MUSTRDTT-1"
          },
          {
           "key":"service_account",
           "value":"gpbootcamp"
          }
        ],
           "Department":"Clothing",
           "subCode":"CLHTT12",
           "Promo":"false",
           "StoreLocationCode": {
           "code":"06",
           "alphaCode":"CA"
          }
       }
     }
   }
```

When I pass my object, above to my method, Jasmine tells me that, the object passed is incorrect, even that is the object I passed to my method. Instead, I see something like my object but place in an object. Its too long, so I have only shown a little bit of the output below:

```
   Object({ Result: Object({ productInformation: 
    '{"inStock":true,"inventoryCode":"PRDCT-QQ011",
     "OrderType":["MERCH-DDD", "APPAREL"],
     "productAttributes":[{"key":"product","value":"Polo Shirt"},...
```

Please help as I have spent many hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: use the assert lib https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=assert

Comment: I cannot just pull in a lib. We are allowed only approved libs

Comment: Can you please add screenshot of complete error, you are doing it correctly .... i am assuming you are missing something in error.